# Amcharts is possible to use panEvents on mobile device (Hybrid)?

Tags: android, charts, amcharts

I would like to use zooming and panning functionality in AmCharts on mobile device. I found configuration directive: panEventsEnabled in http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart

I tried it with combination of the chartScrollbar but without luck.

What I'm doing wrong and how can i use it right on mobile devices?

Many Thanks for any help